# Move 2D character with guiTexture

Tags: unity3d-2dtools

I have a script for left movement that I wanna use with my sprite character in Unity3D.
I want it so that whenever the guiTexture is pressed, the sprite moves.
Here is the script for the movement:

```
public float maxSpeed = 10f;
public GameObject player;


void Start() {}

void FixedUpdate() {

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    if (move < 0) {
        move = move;
    }

    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass you gui texture to the player script and name it "YourGuiTexture".

There are various logical  to detect GuiTexture hit most simplified is below:

**On Keyboard:**

```
public GUITexture YourGuiTexture;

void Update() {

    if (YourGuiTexture.HitTest(Input.mousePosition)   //check if your mouse is on your gui texture
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        if (move < 0) 

         {
             move = move;
         }

         rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
     } 

   }
```

**On Touch Mobile Devices:**

```
public GUITexture YourGuiTexture;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (YourGuiTexture.HitTest(Input.GetTouch(0).position))
    {

        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

            if (move < 0) 

            {
                 move = move;
            }

            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
         }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually mobile devices doesn't have mouse attach and most of them work on touch logic I edited my answer for mobile devices as well have a look.